# Responsive css not working properly

Tags: android, html, css

I have 3 different stylesheets, one for pc screens, one for smartphones like iPhone5S, Samsung Galaxy S4...and another for smaller smartphones, such as my Samsung Galaxy mini.

This is how I wrote my links in my html file:

```
  <link media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 300px), only screen and (max-device-width: 300px)" href="StylesheeetSmallSphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link media="handheld, only screen and (min-width:301px) and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (min-device-width:301px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="StylesheetLargeSPhone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link media="Screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StylesheetPC.css" />
```

On every device, the css applied is the last one. What do I have to change so that every device displays its own css?

Comment: did you add meta viewport tag in your html head section? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: No...but won't using that mean that I have to specify the particular page for a particular device? I am trying to run the same site on different devices, simply by using different css classes.

Comment: No, everything will work fine on desktops, too... try with it, IF syntax of link attributes is ok...

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean EXCLUSIVELY the last one or ALSO the last one?